# Angular 4 DI and @Optional parameter with default value

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I have a class with a constructor which has one parameter with default value.
like so

```
export class MyClass {
    constructor(injector: Injector, 
                private translationService: 
                TranslateService, 
                public errorRoute: string = '/error') {
        super();
}
```

I know that DI can't just inject a plain string but I expected Angulars DI to handle default values.
But Angular complains `No provider for String!`

Ok, then I tried it with `@Optional() public errorRoute: string = '/error'`
Now Angular doesn't complain but injects `NULL` as value.

I know I can workaround the problem, but I like to know if I can get DI to handle my situation and if not: why not?

Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to inject it in constructor? Do you create component manually?

Comment: No, everything is handled by angular.
It's more of a general question

Comment: So it will always equal `/error` Then you can use property on class

Comment: See my edit in the comment above. This class is from a library project. So it may be always '/error' for Application A but something different for Application B.

Comment: All parameters are supposed to be a tokens that are declarer by angular DI mechanism. If you didn't specify how angular should resolve dependency and specify @Optional then is will always be `null`

Comment: but why does angular even try to resolve it when it has a default value?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/view/provider.ts#L344 I think it's because some logic is related with `null` value for optional parameter See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12551

Comment: so I assume it's just not possible :(
If you add your comment as an answer I'll mark it as solution